# How do I show a spinner while waiting for an AJAX request in Mithril JS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mithril.js

I'm using Mithril JS in a project and I'm having trouble understanding exactly how to go about hooking into the Ajax lifecycle. Like if I have an Ajax request takes awhile, I want to show a spinner. Pretty basic, but I can't seem to figure out how that can happen.

I want to use the same container for the spinner as the content that the Ajax request is looking for.

Here's my setup:

```
var Thing = function (data) {
  var p = m.prop;
  this.title = p(data.title);
  this.timestamp = p(moment.unix(data.timestamp));
}

Thing.list = function(options) {
  m.request({method: "GET", url: "/things.json", type: Thing, background: true});
};

MyApp.components.thingsList = {
  controller: function ThingListController() {
    this.things = m.prop([]);
    Thing.list().then(this.things).then(m.redraw);
  },

  view: function thingListView(ctrl) {
    return m('div#thing-tab', [
      m('ul#things', [
        ctrl.things().map(thingView)
      ])
    ]);
  }
};

function thingView(thing) {
  ...some view stuff...
}
```

I've got it working the way I want, but I just can't figure out how to hook into the ajax lifecycle. Again, I just wanna show a spinner when the request starts and then replace that with the result of the ajax request.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way is to wrap `m.request` in another function that returns both the completion state (based on a flag that you set via the m.request promise chain), and the data, and then use the `background: true` option to prevent the deferral of the redraw, and also bind `m.redraw` to the promise chain in order to have redrawing happen after the request.

This was originally described here: https://github.com/lhorie/mithril.js/issues/192

```
var requestWithFeedback = function(args) {
  var completed = m.prop(false)
  var complete = function(value) {
    completed(true)
    return value
  }
  args.background = true
  return {
    data: m.request(args).then(complete, complete).then(function(value) {
      m.redraw()
      return value
    }),
    ready: completed
  }
}

var MyController = function() {
  this.things = requestWithFeedback({method: "GET", url: "/things"})
}
var myView = function(ctrl) {
  return !ctrl.things.ready() ? m("img[src=loading.gif]") : m("ul", [
    ctrl.things.data().map(function(thing) {
      return m("li", thing.name)
    })
  ]) 
}

m.module(document.body, {controller: MyController, view: myView})
```

Comment: Thanks Leo! That's exactly what I needed. Really liking Mithril so far btw :)

Comment: Why do you pass in `complete` twice? `m.request(args).then(complete, complete)...`

Answer (score 3):

I found what I think is an elegant way to do this, based on the principle that Mithril re-renders the entire UI (with differencing) on model update. The following example is for saving an inline update.

When I have some part of the model which is changing via AJAX, I set a temporary flag in the model (you can as easily do it in the view-state model if you want to keep it separate), and on completion, I just delete the flag and invoke m.redraw():

```
function updateRecord(ctl,evt,row,idx,rcd) {
    rcd._action="save";
    apiSender({ method: "PATCH", url: apiUrl, data: dropFlags(rcd) }).then(done,fail).then(null,logObject);

    function done(rspdta) {
        delete rcd._action;
        m.redraw();
        };

    function fail(rspdta) {
        ajaxError(ctl,rspdta,"Update customer "+rcd.CustomerId+" ("+rcd.ContactName+")");
        rcd._action="edit";
        m.redraw();
        };
    }
```

In the view, which is rebuilt from the model data, I condition on the flag:

```
if     (rcd._action=="edit"   ) { con=crtListRecordView_Edit   (rcd,idx             ); }
else if(rcd._action=="save"   ) { con=crtListRecordView_Waiting(rcd,idx,"Saving"    ); }
else if(rcd._action=="delete" ) { con=crtListRecordView_Waiting(rcd,idx,"Deleting"  ); }
else if(rcd._action=="merge"  ) { con=crtListRecordView_Waiting(rcd,idx,"Merging"   ); }
else if(rcd._action=="refresh") { con=crtListRecordView_Waiting(rcd,idx,"Refreshing"); }
else                            { con=crtListRecordView_Normal (rcd,idx             ); }
return m("tr", con);
```

This allows multiple concurrent actions on different records, and a polished, clear and unobtrusive feedback to the user.

Here's what it looks like:

Normal:

> [image: Normal]

Editing:

> [image: Editing]

Saving:

> [image: Saving]