# How do I use the value from m.request in MithrilJS when using background:true?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mithril.js

I'm using m.request in a project, and since I have a request that can be potentially long running, I want to run it with `background:true`. However, it seems like the value never gets set to the generated `m.prop`.

I've made a jsFiddle with an example based on this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25372341): http://jsfiddle.net/u5wuyokz/9/

What I expect to happen is that the second call to the view should have the response value in `ctrl.test.data()`, but it seems to still have `undefined`. At `Point A` in the code, it logs the correct value. However, at `Point B`, it logs `false, undefined` and then `true, undefined`.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something incorrectly, or if this the expected behavior.

Code from the jsFiddle:

```
var requestWithFeedback = function(args) {
  var completed = m.prop(false)
  var complete = function(value) {
    completed(true)
    return value
  }
  args.background = true
  return {
    data: m.request(args).then(complete, complete).then(function(value) {
        //Point A
        console.log(value);
        m.redraw()
        return value
    }),
    ready: completed
  }
};

var mod = {
        controller : function() {
            this.test = requestWithFeedback({
                method : "POST",
                url : "/echo/json/",
                serialize: serialize, 
                config: asFormUrlEncoded,
                data : {
                    json : "{\"name\" : \"testing\"}"
                }
            });
        },
        view : function(ctrl) {
            //Point B
            console.log(ctrl.test.ready(), ctrl.test.data());
            return m("div", ctrl.test.ready() ? 'loaded' : 'loading');
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** The problem is that `m.redraw` is called before the data is assigned. Instead you could create a `m.prop` for `data` and let the ajax request assign that value when completed. `requestWithFeedback` will then look like this:

```
var requestWithFeedback = function(args) {
  var data = m.prop()
  args.background = true
  m.request(args).then(data).then(function() { m.redraw() })

  return {
    data: data,
    ready: function() {return !!data()}
  }
};
```

Here's a modified version of your fiddle using this code: http://jsfiddle.net/u5wuyokz/11/

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! Do you know if anything has changed since when the SO question I referenced was posted? The answer came from Leo Horie himself, so I assumed that it would work, but as written, it was giving me issues.

Comment: You're right, it looks like it should work since a Mithril promise returns a GetterSetter. I'll tinker with it some more, if I cannot find a good reason I'll file an issue on github.

Answer (score 1):

When using `background: true`, Mithril's [components branch](https://github.com/lhorie/mithril.js/tree/components) or [any other system](https://gist.github.com/barneycarroll/0e3c1b9811b47c012b13) that executes controllers in the same 'tick' as views, `m.request`s made in the controller will not have resolved by the time they are invoked by their respective views.

It is therefore [recommended](http://lhorie.github.io/mithril/mithril.request.html#rendering-before-web-service-requests-finish) to always use the `initialValue` property of `m.request` if you're using `background: true`. The canonical example is to have an initial value of `[]` when you make a request for a list of entries:

```
var projectsModule = {
  controller(){
    this.projects = m.request( {
      background   : true,
      initialValue : [],
      url          : '/projects.json'
    } );
  },
  view( ctrl ){
    return m( 'ul', ctrl.projects.map( 
      project => m( 'li', project.name )
    ) )
  }
}
```

This solves the practical problems of views breaking when they expect to be able to work with `m.request` return values in a generic way, but doesn't address the more complex case in your example, where a `ready` flag is desirable to indicate a 'loading' state. I have a generic API that consumes a model getter function and an optional initial value. It has `next`, `then`, `hasResolved`, `isPending`, `get` and `set` methods: this allows views to be more flexible in the way they query the state of asynchronous models. `hasResolved` indicates whether the method has ever resolved, and `next` returns a promise that will resolve either with the current request, or when the next request is resolved if `isPending` is false.